# Scraping dynamic data with imacro to excell

Tags: web-scraping, imacros

I want to scrape dynamic data  (refreshable every 4 seconds and it's a number ) with imacro and represent that number changing along the time in excell ( or any other way ).

How can i do this ? Imacro, as further as i know can get the data but can it scrap a dynamic one .

The code is from a basketball game on [Flashscore](http://www.flashscore.com/basketball/) ,exactly the scores table between 2 teams :
Here is  an example for a game table

```
<table id="parts" class="parts-first horizontal">
    <tbody>
            <tr class="odd">
                <td class="score"><span class="rb">69</span</td>
                <td class="score part"><span class="p1_home">31</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="even">
                <td class="score"><span class="rb">63</span></td>
                <td class="score part"><span class="p1_away">17</span></td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

that gives those two lines data:
    
        
                
                    69
                    31
                
                
                    63
                    17

Comment: Provide a code example of what you have tried. It makes it easier for people to help you.

Comment: @DavidWatts i didn't try anything , i'm just asking if making  the project possible with imacro ..

Comment: In brief, the answer is “yes” and ‘iMacros’ can write the data you need in a file of csv-format which is readable with ‘Excel’.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the more detailed answer with a code.

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TD ATTR=CLASS:"score" EXTRACT=TXT
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/\\d+/)[0];")
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TD ATTR=CLASS:"score part" EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=scores.csv
TAG POS=2 TYPE=TD ATTR=CLASS:"score" EXTRACT=TXT
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/\\d+/)[0];")
TAG POS=2 TYPE=TD ATTR=CLASS:"score part" EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=scores.csv
WAIT SECONDS=4
```

Play this macro in loop mode (button ‘Play (Loop)’) with the max. number of loops equal to a very big integer (e.g. 99999).

Comment: it worked fine .. but i don't see a difference when not setting the lines ''SET !EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!E ......"  ? so what's the purpose of them?

Comment: You may omit these lines, if you wish so. Their purpose is to extract only digital signs from the ‘!EXTRACT’ variable. (When I tested the code, in the first extracted value there were several non-printing characters for some reasons.)

Comment: thank you very much for your help .One other thing : how can i get the csv file without comma and quotes ; only spaces between the numbers :)

Comment: If you’re playing iim-code, it’s impossible to change the structure of a csv-file by means of ‘iMacros’ and post factum you can only do this manually (Find -> Replace) with something like ‘Notepad’. However, if you (1) apply Firefox and ‘iMacros’ extension for it, (2) have js-script for this goal and (3) have written the code using ‘Components.classes’, you may succeed in getting a proper file.