# imacros strip double quotes from date extract

Tags: csv, replace, formatting, export-to-csv, imacros

Hi I have the following line in my imacros code .

```
  ADD !EXTRACT {{!NOW:dd/mm/yy}}
```

How can I format the above code so that it strips off the double quotes when extracting to a csv file ? Thanks

Comment: View the last comment to the post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30892937/scraping-dynamic-data-with-imacro-to-excell

Comment: Thanks will give it a read and a try.

Comment: I can write the script that was outlined there. For more details contact me via e-mail ( shugarjs@gmail.com ).